# Is it possible to direct a file to my C++ program using Mingw, when I run it from terminal?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, io-redirection

I want to run my program the way it takes the input from a file while I run it.
I mean you can do it in Linux terminal like `./a.out < example.txt` and it reads the file to the specific variables.
I want to do this in VSCode using Mingw, but I dont know how to pull it off.

An example program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

int main () {
    string name;
    cout << "hello world!" << endl;
    cout << "ur name: " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "ur name is " << name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And in my VSCode terminal I want: `g++ main.cpp -> ./a.exe < name.txt`

And `name.txt` contains just a name.

Comment: If you haven't done it yet, then please read [Using GCC with MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). Then edit `launch.json` to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Redirection (`>` for output and `<` for input, or `|` to use the output of one program as input for the other) can be handled using standard input and output, which is `cin` and `cout` respectively in C++.

So `cin >> name;` in your program will read from `name.txt` when the application is started with `./a.exe < name.txt`.

Note that `./a.exe < name.txt` is a Unix notation, which will work in MSYS shell too, but when using Windows you should just run `a.exe < name.txt`, or if you need to specify a path something like: `C:\Temp\a.exe < C:\Temp\name.txt`.

Comment: I got this error message while trying a.exe < name.txt

At line:1 char:7
+ a.exe < name.txt
+       ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported

Comment: Looks like VSCode doesn't do redirection. Run your program from command line or rewrite it to read from a file instead of `cin`.